# Dynamically Updating Form Field With jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm building a cost calculator that takes an integer from a text box, if it is within two certain figures a cost is then passed to a cost field on the form. I was going to use PHP but struggled getting an ajax call to work, here is what I've come up with so far in jQuery:

```
$("#message_wordcount").change(function() {
        var p;
        var service = $("#message_service").val();
        var wc=parseInt($("#message_wordcount").val(), 10);

        if($(service=="Critique")
        {
            if (wc<="1200") {
                var p=2.5;                  
             } else if (wc>"1200" && wc<="2500")    {
                var p=5;
             } else if (wc>"2500" && wc<="4000")    {
                var p=10;
             } else if (wc>"4000" && wc<="6500")    {
                var p=15;
             } else if (wc>"6500" && wc<="8000")    {
                var p=20;
             } else if (wc>"8000" && wc<="12000")   {
                var p=25;
             } else if (wc>"12000" && wc<="16000")  {
                var p=30;
             } else if (wc>"16000" && wc<="20500")  {
                var p=35;
             } else if (wc>"20500" && wc<="22500")  {
                var p=40;
             } else if (wc>"22500" && wc<="25500")  {
                var p=45;
             } else if (wc>"25500" && wc<="27000")  {
                var p=50;
             } else if (wc>"27000" && wc<="29999")  {
                var p=55;
             } else if (wc>"29999" && wc<="33600")  {
                var p=60;
             } else if (wc>"33600" && wc<="36100")  {
                var p=65;
             } else if (wc>"36100" && wc<="38700")  {
                var p=70;
             } else if (wc>"38701" && wc<="40700")  {
                var p=75;
             } else if (wc>"40700" && wc<="42700")  {
                var p=80;
             } else if (wc>"42700" && wc<="45000")  {
                var p=85;
             } else if (wc>"45000" && wc<="48000")  {
                var p=90;
             } else if (wc>"48000" && wc<="49500")  {
                var p=95;
             } else if (wc>"49500" && wc<="52000")  {
                var p=100;
             } else if (wc>"52000" && wc<="54500")  {
                var p=105;
             } else if (wc>"54500" && wc<="57000")  {
                var p=110;
             } else if (wc>"57000" && wc<="59999")  {
                var p=115;
             } else if (wc>"59999" && wc<="63000")  {
                var p=120;
             } else if (wc>"63000" && wc<="68000")  {
                var p=125;
             } else if (wc>"68000" && wc<="72000")  {
                var p=130;
             } else if (wc>"72000" && wc<="76000")  {
                var p=135;
             } else if (wc>"76000" && wc<="79999")  {
                var p=140;
             } else if (wc>"79999" && wc<="85999")  {
                var p=145;
             } else if (wc>"85999" && wc<="92000")  {
                var p=150;
             } else if (wc>"92000" && wc<="99999")  {
                var p=155;
             }  else if (wc>"99999" && wc<="105000")    {
                var p=160;
             }  else if (wc>"105000" && wc<="110000")   {
                var p=170;
             }  else if (wc>"110000" && wc<="115000")   {
                var p=180;
             }  else if (wc>"115000" && wc<="120000")   {
                var p=190;
             }  else if (wc>"120000" && wc<="125000")   {
                var p=200;
             }  else if (wc>"125000" && wc<="130000")   {
                var p=210;
             }  else if (wc>"130000" && wc<="135000")   {
                var p=220;
             }  else if (wc>"135000" && wc<="139999")   {
                var p=230;
             }  else if (wc>"139999" && wc<="150000")   {
                var p=240;
             }  else if (wc>"150000" && wc<="159999")   {
                var p=245;
             }  else if (wc>"159999" && wc<="170000")   {
                var p=250;
             }  else if (wc>"170000" && wc<="180000")   {
                var p=260;
             }  else if (wc>"180000" && wc<="185000")   {
                var p=270;
             }  else if (wc>"185000" && wc<="192000")   {
                var p=280;
             }  else if (wc>"192000" && wc<="199999")   {
                var p=290;
             }  else if (wc>"199999" && wc<="250000")   {
                var p=300;
             }
             $("#message_cost").val(p);
        }
     });
```

And here is my markup:

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
                <p><label for="name">Name: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
                <p><label for="message_email">Email: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
                <p><label for="message_service">Service: <span>*</span><br><select name="message_service"><option value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_service']); ?>Critique">Critique</option>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_service']); ?>Standard Edit">Standard Edit</option>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_service']); ?>Comprehensive">Comprehensive</option>
                </select></label></p>
                <p><label for="message_wordcount">Word Count: <span>*</span> <br><input  id="message_wordcount" type="text" name="message_wordcount" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_wordcount']); ?>"></label> &nbsp <a href="#" id="cC">Calculate Cost</a></p>
                <p><label for="message_cost">Total Cost: <br><input id="message_cost" type="text" name="message_cost" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_cost']); ?>" readonly></label></p>
                <p><label for="message_text">Message: <span>*</span> <br><textarea type="text" name="message_text"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
                <p><label for="message_human">Human Verification: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                <p><input type="submit"></p>
              </form>
```

However nothing seems to happen when the wordcount box is changed - I could get the function to return the price prior to integrating it with the form.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Once declared `var p`. why are you declaring it every-time?

Comment: If you declared `var p` right at the beginning, why are you re-declaring it inside every condition? Just `p = something` would be enough. But that's not the issue here.

Comment: you need to remove the `$(` in `if($(service=="Critique")` this is invalid syntax

Comment: Try replacing `.val()` with `.prep("value")`, and `.val(value)` with `.prep("value", value)`.

Comment: I've made all the changes above and have swapped val for prep where needed although I'm not sure if this is the right syntax:
var service = $("#message_service").prep("value"); and:
$("#message_cost").prep(p, value);

Comment: @iKettles, and.... Did it fix it? Are you still having problems??

Comment: I made the syntax changes as above but still no joy I'm afraid

Comment: Here's a fiddle which might make this a bit easier to sort: http://jsfiddle.net/pVDdL/ I've removed the PHP POSTs for easier reading

Answer (score 1):

Check the below fiddle. Hope this helps you

To get string count - [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/V6QLq/)
To get word count - [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/V6QLq/1/)

Instead of parseInt, get the length of the string and instead of change function give keyup function.

JS here

```
$("#message_wordcount").keyup(function() {
    var p;
    var wc=$("#message_wordcount").val().length; 
    if (wc<="1200") {
        var p=2.5;                  
    } else if (wc>"1200" && wc<="2500")    {
        var p=5;
    } else if (wc>"2500" && wc<="4000")    {
        var p=10;
    } else if (wc>"4000" && wc<="6500")    {
        var p=15;
    } else if (wc>"6500" && wc<="8000")    {
        var p=20;
    } else if (wc>"8000" && wc<="12000")   {
        var p=25;
    } else if (wc>"12000" && wc<="16000")  {
        var p=30;
    } else if (wc>"16000" && wc<="20500")  {
        var p=35;
    } else if (wc>"20500" && wc<="22500")  {
        var p=40;
    } else if (wc>"22500" && wc<="25500")  {
        var p=45;
    } else if (wc>"25500" && wc<="27000")  {
        var p=50;
    } else if (wc>"27000" && wc<="29999")  {
        var p=55;
    } else if (wc>"29999" && wc<="33600")  {
        var p=60;
    } else if (wc>"33600" && wc<="36100")  {
        var p=65;
    } else if (wc>"36100" && wc<="38700")  {
        var p=70;
    } else if (wc>"38701" && wc<="40700")  {
        var p=75;
    } else if (wc>"40700" && wc<="42700")  {
        var p=80;
    } else if (wc>"42700" && wc<="45000")  {
        var p=85;
    } else if (wc>"45000" && wc<="48000")  {
        var p=90;
    } else if (wc>"48000" && wc<="49500")  {
        var p=95;
    } else if (wc>"49500" && wc<="52000")  {
        var p=100;
    } else if (wc>"52000" && wc<="54500")  {
        var p=105;
    } else if (wc>"54500" && wc<="57000")  {
        var p=110;
    } else if (wc>"57000" && wc<="59999")  {
        var p=115;
    } else if (wc>"59999" && wc<="63000")  {
        var p=120;
    } else if (wc>"63000" && wc<="68000")  {
        var p=125;
    } else if (wc>"68000" && wc<="72000")  {
        var p=130;
    } else if (wc>"72000" && wc<="76000")  {
        var p=135;
    } else if (wc>"76000" && wc<="79999")  {
        var p=140;
    } else if (wc>"79999" && wc<="85999")  {
        var p=145;
    } else if (wc>"85999" && wc<="92000")  {
        var p=150;
    } else if (wc>"92000" && wc<="99999")  {
        var p=155;
    }  else if (wc>"99999" && wc<="105000")    {
        var p=160;
    }  else if (wc>"105000" && wc<="110000")   {
        var p=170;
    }  else if (wc>"110000" && wc<="115000")   {
        var p=180;
    }  else if (wc>"115000" && wc<="120000")   {
        var p=190;
    }  else if (wc>"120000" && wc<="125000")   {
        var p=200;
    }  else if (wc>"125000" && wc<="130000")   {
        var p=210;
    }  else if (wc>"130000" && wc<="135000")   {
        var p=220;
    }  else if (wc>"135000" && wc<="139999")   {
        var p=230;
    }  else if (wc>"139999" && wc<="150000")   {
        var p=240;
    }  else if (wc>"150000" && wc<="159999")   {
        var p=245;
    }  else if (wc>"159999" && wc<="170000")   {
        var p=250;
    }  else if (wc>"170000" && wc<="180000")   {
        var p=260;
    }  else if (wc>"180000" && wc<="185000")   {
        var p=270;
    }  else if (wc>"185000" && wc<="192000")   {
        var p=280;
    }  else if (wc>"192000" && wc<="199999")   {
        var p=290;
    }  else if (wc>"199999" && wc<="250000")   {
        var p=300;
    }
    $("#message_cost").val(p);
});
```

HTML form

```
<input  id="message_wordcount" type="text" name="message_wordcount" value="" />
<input id="message_cost" value="" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much however I'm finding that when I enter a value into the wordcount box it seems to default to the first condition and doesn't update with any further values.

Comment: Was just working through this, #message_service was wrong too, you had no input with an id of #message_service

Comment: @iKettles, give id "message_service" to your select box

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam - How is using the length preferable over parseInt? He needs the word count value to determine the correct message cost.

Comment: I implemented the changes Saranya made and corrected the ID for the select. Still no joy :( Here's what I've got now: http://jsfiddle.net/pVDdL/5/

Comment: @iKettles - You have not included the js, check fiddle now - http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/pVDdL/6/ . Its working fine

Comment: @FrancisGagnon, I have removed parseInt and given two demo. One for string and another for word count.

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam Silly me! Although regardless of the number I enter it's still evaluating to the first condition?

Comment: @iKettles - Give string more than 1200 characters, it will enter into 2nd condition

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam Apologies, I think I was a bit unclear in my original post, the wordcount field is just for the number of words not the words themselves. I've swapped out .length for parseInt now and it works perfectly, I really appreciate the help guys!! Thanks

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam - The string length approach doesn't work at all because the message cost is calculated based on the number of words. Your example that splits on spaces and counts the words is confusing because you are splitting the contents of the word count textbox instead of the message text area.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event is only triggered when focus leaves the input field. You can use something like `keyup` instead to react while focus is still on the input field.

As @Liam has pointed out, you also have a syntax error in your code. Most modern browsers come with developer tools that help you track down run-time errors. If you are for example using Chrome, you can press F12 to start the developer tools. Click the Console tab and then refresh your web page to see a list of run-time errors.

Comment: Again, as with the other question, how does this help? Your just changing change to key press. This isn't what the OP is asking for. *However nothing seems to happen when the wordcount box is changed*

Comment: It is a very common misconception that the `change` event gets triggered as soon as the contents of an `<input type=text/>` are changed. Most people are surprised to find that you have to remove focus from the input field in order to trigger it. I believe the question of the OP stems from this very misunderstanding. However, as you have pointed out, there are also syntax errors in the code which need to be cleared up as well.